# Console warning if statement not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("What would you like to search\n");
    printf("Here are the options\n");
    printf("s : How are you\n");
    printf("c : What would you like to search\n");

    scanf("%s",&buffer);

    if(buffer == 's')
        printf("iam fine\n");
    else if (buffer == 'c')
        printf("What would you like to search\n");

    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    system(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

**Console Errors(program not functioning correctly)**

```
C:\Users\sc\Documents\ForumCode\test\foo.c|12|warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[1024]'|
C:\Users\sc\Documents\ForumCode\test\foo.c|13|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|
C:\Users\sc\Documents\ForumCode\test\foo.c|15|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|

||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 3 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Read and understand the warnings. It's not the compiler that's wrong.

Comment: You didn't even ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be scanf("%s",buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Your `buffer` variable is an array of characters, but in your if statement, you're trying to compare this array to a single character.

Perhaps what you're looking for is `if (buffer[0] == 's')`